# sinonStub.called prints false, though I am calling the function

Tags: node.js, sinon-chai

I am running test on node js app using sinon. I want the sinonStub.called to be true but this prints false. I am calling the function indirectly( function call within function). I have given code snippet below

**spec.js**

```
describe.only('creating stub for Accounts method',function(){
   mockResponse=
        [
         {
         "AccountID": "xyz",
           ....
         }
         ]

        req1= {
            user:{
                id:""
            },
       },

       res1= {
       json:sinon.spy()//Is this correct
       }

     it('should call  getActivatedAccounts and always this mock response',function(){
        var getAccountsStub=sinon.stub(devices,'getAccounts').returns(mockResponse);
        devices.getActivatedResponse(req1,res1);

        console.log(getAccountsStub.called);//I expect this to be called
    })
```

**Actual.js**

```
function getActivatedResponse(req, res) {

    if (!req.user || !req.user.id) {
      let reply = {
        status : "SUCCESS",
        data : []
      }
      res.json(reply);
      //console.log(reply);
    } else {
      getActivatedAccounts(req.user.id).then(
        function(reply) { 
          res.json(reply);
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
function getAccounts(Id){
....
....
returns promise;
}
```

Comment: This is really messy. You expect the `getAccountsStub` to be called but you aren't calling that through the `getActivatedResponse` - you are calling `getActivatedAccounts` - are all of the method names correct?

Comment: Hi Mavi, I am sorry :) ,I agree is code bit mess.  d the function getActivatedAccounts is called within getActivatedResponse. So I thought by just calling outer function, inner function is obviously gets called

Comment: I am new to this testing, let me know if Iam wrong